# MySQL query to work out the manager of the oldest employee

Tags: mysql

I am working on a database within phpMyAdmin.

I am looking for a query that will generate the manager of the oldest employee.

I will be linking different databases for this.

The first database is called `person` and has the following fields:

```
[firstname]
[surname]
[DOB]
```

The second database is called `manager_allocation` and I would like to use the following fields:

```
[person_id]
[line_manager_id]
```

Comment: You write a query for the oldest employee, get their ID and use that as a subquery for selecting the manager information.

Comment: Note that things you call `database` are actually `tables`.

Comment: And the things called fields are columns - although this is a subtler distinction.

Answer (score 0):

To get the oldest employee from the table `person` you could use a query like this:

```
select personid, firstname, surname, DOB
from person
order by DOB desc
limit 1
```

if you want to consider that more than one person have the same DOB, the query will be like this:

```
select personid, firstname, surname, DOB
from person
where DOB = (select min(dob) from person)
```

to return the manager (or the managers if more than one person share the maximum age) you could use a query like this:

```
select line_manager_id
from manager_allocation
where
  person_id IN (
    select personid from person
    where DOB = (select min(dob) from person)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use min or max function to get oldest or newest date.

```
select line_manager_id from person inner join manager_allocation on person.person_id=manager_allocation.person_id where DOB=(select min(DOB) from person)
```